# Http Get and Post (name value pair)

Tags: android, client-server

I am creating an application for storing some information into server and retrieving the same from server.

The *Application 1* for example will store in to the server using `POST` method and the *Application 2* will retrieve the same from server using `Get` method.

The information stored on the server has structure like this: `(lat, lon, address)`.

Is it possible to generate separate user id for all users who use *Application 2* so that only the required location information will be displayed and not everything?

Answer (score 1):

If your device is a phone then you can use TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() this will be unique for any phone.

For any device you can use [Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html) as explained, for example, [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/03/get-android-device-id.html) however they say it may not be unique.

You can also generate a pseudo ID yourself using [Build.MODEL, Build.ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) and other such constants.